# Symfony 6 переопределить метод getUser

Tags: symfony

В проекте к пользователям привязаны фирмы.
базы данных

```
user, firm, userFirm
```

после авториацзии нужно получить ID фирмы. для этого хочу переопределить метод getUser, чтобы в выводе сразу было значение и фирмы.
каким образом можно реализовать такое?